# Scratch on cat’s head

Tags: cats, wound-care

My cat is outdoor and it’s texhnically feral. It comes in my house for food/shelter and to sleep. But it usually goes outside and roam around my neiguborhood. Today I came home and noticed there’s a wound on his head. He seems fine and I think it’s bothering him bc he keeps trying to scratch it. What should I do?? Does it look infected or dangerous?

I also pet it and I might accidentally touch the wound

[image]

Comment: there is two main causes for this type of wounds,cat claws or ticks.cat claws will often cause an abcess that might need to get drained and cleaned by your vet,ticks too can cause this type of wounds and depending on where you live tick bites can be very dangerous to all animals..